# read after updates of column in Cassandra is getting delayed response for few columns

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, consistency

I am trying to read values from Cassandra after updating few columns. Consistency for Read is LOCAL_ONE.
Data for columns is coming with delay of around 10sec. Is there any workaround for this issue. No load on server.

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: there is too little information in your question - that's strange situation, but there are too many unknowns - how data is written (consistency levels, etc.). How many serves in the cluster, where they are located, what is the topology, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex for comment. Write consistency is LOCAL_QUOROM.This  cluster is 6 node cluster located on premise VM with network topology replication.

Comment: start with the checks from the second document in this list: https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/bestPractices.html